# Exporting Apple HealthKit data

Tags: mysql, healthkit

I export Health app data(Apple) and want to import into my database for further development.However, when I run the following cmd:

```
load xml local infile 'PATHTOFILE'
into Table Record
rows identified by '<Record>'
```

It shows that:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Nothing happened.
I try to modify(romove two tags) the file exported from apple health app.

```
<ExportDate value="20150424105126+0800"/>
<Me HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth="" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex="0" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBloodType="0"/>
```

I succeed.
 
I wonder is it a bug of Mysql that can't find the tag `<Record>` as it is not the first(`ExportDate`) child node of `HeathData` 
Or the xml file Apple exported is not well-formed?
OOr the xml file I dealt with is not in the 3 situation on refman of mysql.(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html)

Thanks in advance.

xml file(the first N rows):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HealthData locale="en_CA">
<ExportDate value="20150424105126+0800"/>
<Me HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth="" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex="0" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBloodType="0"/>
<Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount" source="Mi Fit" unit="count" startDate="20150423120000+0800" endDate="20150423120100+0800" value="11.5365" recordCount="1"/>
<Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount" source="Mi Fit" unit="count" startDate="20150423120100+0800" endDate="20150423120200+0800" value="11.5365" recordCount="1"/>
<Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount" source="Mi Fit" unit="count" startDate="20150423120200+0800" endDate="20150423120300+0800" value="11.5365" recordCount="1"/>
```

Comment: Have you run the XML through one of those online format checkers?

Comment: The xml file is fine, I find that the problem may occur in the usage of 'row identified by *', it may not be suitable on my xml file. Thanks anyway~

Comment: Yeah I've never loaded XML into MySQL like that. Just CSV. Anyway good luck!

Comment: Can you describe the table Record? Maybe a problem with a unique key. HealthData samples have a unique UUID and I would export/import the UUID to make sure all records are imported exactly once.